# Mapping Network Drive To Computer OU With GPO

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy, network-drive

I have a computer that I want to map a network drive to no matter who logs into it. I have crated a security  group linking the member to the computer. I created a GPO and added the security group to the security filtering in the GPO. In the GPO under user configuration -> preferences -> windows setting -> drive maps.  I setup my map drive. I logged into the computer a few times, and the drive never was mapped. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

consider to give every body a net use statement in the startup scripts ? that was the old style simplest way we have. and we need it anyway. Put a hook so it will call the update.bat at network drive at the end is always useful. "idea: you may one day need to give every user a new program". Also, you can write pretty customize scripts to map different path for different peoples.

```
User Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Logon > Run these programs at logon
```

Comment: I would really like to use the drive maps, instead of the old way. But if I don't get it work here soon I will have to try something else.